# How do Azure WebJobs prioritize messages when monitoring multiple queues?

Tags: azure, message-queue, azure-webjobs

I'm using Azure WebJobs as part of a project at work. These are configured as continuously running jobs that monitor a number of different queues. As queue messages are received they cause various API commands to be run. The issue I have is that some of the API commands run quickly (ie. a few seconds) and some run slowly (several minutes), and I'm not sure how best to split the queue handlers between the WebJobs.

For example, I could put all of the slow API command handlers in one WebJob and all of the quick handlers in a different WebJob. My concern is that the "slow" WebJob process would always be busy whereas the "quick" WebJob process would be idling most of the time.

Another approach would be to mix quick and slow handlers in the same WebJob project. My concern with that would be the quicker handlers starving the slower ones of attention, or vice versa.

A third approach would be to have a separate WebJob for each individual message handler, but given the number of message types we have to deal with I'd rather not go down that route. It also seems like overkill to be honest.

I was wondering if anyone had encountered a similar scenario and could offer any insight into how Azure WebJobs choose which message to handle when they are monitoring multiple queues? Numerous internet searches have failed to turn-up any guidance or help in this area. To be clear, I'm not really after opinions as to which approach people *think* would be best; I'm looking for answers from people who have actually dealt with this kind of problem and can say with some degree of certainty which of the different approaches would be best given the way the Azure WebJobs API currently prioritizes queue message handling.

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple functions listening on different queues, the SDK will call them in parallel when messages are received simultaneously. You can not set which queue should be processed first.

Depending on you configuration, you will handle them parallel. If you think that some executions will stall others, you can split the handling in multiple webjobs and scale them seperately.